# New titleclass not counted in the table of contents

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, titlesec, titletoc

The following defines a new `titleclass` which I would prefer not counted in the table of contents defined.  How can this be achieved?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
      {\bfseries\Large}
      {\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
      {1ex}
      {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filleft}
      [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]

\titleclass{\sample}{straight}[\chapter]
\newcounter{sample}
\renewcommand{\thesample}{\arabic{sample}}

\titlespacing*{\sample}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1ex plus .2ex}

\titleformat{\sample}[block]
{\titlerule*[.6em]{\bfseries.}\normalfont\sffamily\Large\leavevmode\\[-11pt]}
{\bfseries\Large Sample \thechapter.\thesample}
{0pt}
{\enspace\bfseries}
[]

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Test Unnumbered Chapter}
    \startcontents[chapters]%
    \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
    \sample{ex1}
    \sample{ex2}
    \chapter{Test Numbered Chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide a (possible empty) `\titlecontents` for `sample` and start the partial ToC at the desired level below `sample`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
      {\bfseries\Large}
      {\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
      {1ex}
      {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filleft}
      [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]

\titleclass{\sample}{straight}[\chapter]
\newcounter{sample}
\renewcommand{\thesample}{\thechapter.\arabic{sample}}

\titlespacing*{\sample}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1ex plus .2ex}

\titleformat{\sample}[block]
{\titlerule*[.6em]{\bfseries.}\normalfont\sffamily\Large\leavevmode\\[-11pt]}
{\bfseries\Large Sample \thesample}
{0pt}
{\enspace\bfseries}
[]

\titlecontents{sample}
  {}{}{}{}

\begin{document}
    \startcontents[chapters]%
    \chapter{Test Unnumbered Chapter}
    \printcontents[chapters]{}{2}{}
    \section{Test Section}
    \sample{ex1}
    \sample{ex2}
    \chapter{Test Numbered Chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much my friend. Why the change from `\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}` to `\printcontents[chapters]{}{2}{}`?

Comment: @azetina You're welcome!. The new sectional unit has level `1`, so you need to set the start level to `2` (the new level for sections) to not include it; if you leave the level at `1`, then you'll get an error since the new unit is requested to be included in the partial ToC but no real definition for the formatting in the ToC was given (`\titlecontents{sample}` in my example doesn't really declares a formatting; it only makes the partial ToC aware of the new unit).

Comment: According to http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316356/2041 the bracketed argument to `\titlecontents` is manditory.