# Error in creating new title class and excluding from ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I am trying to create a new title class somewhat like a section but that is not included in the ToC. But when I use `\titlecontents{exercise}{}{}{}{}` it does not compile. How can I fix this?

Here is a mwe:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Exercise Environment
%\titlecontents{exercise}{}{}{}{} % should remove from ToC but does not work

\titleclass{\exercise}{straight}[\chapter]
\newcounter{exercise}
\renewcommand{\theexercise}{\thechapter.\arabic{exercise}}

\titleformat{\exercise}[block]
    {\normalfont\sffamily\Large}
    {\bfseries\Large Exercise \theexercise}
    {.5em}
    {\bfseries}

\titleformat{name=\exercise,numberless}[block]
    {\titlerule*[.6em]{\bfseries.}
    \vspace{0.9ex}%
    \normalfont\sffamily\Large}
    {\bfseries ##1}
    {.5em}
    {\bfseries}

\titlespacing*{\exercise}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1ex plus .2ex}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{sample}

\section{A test section}
\exercise{}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) (section **6.1. A ten-minute guide to `titletoc`**):

> ```
> \dottedcontents{<section>}[<left>]{<above-code>}
>                {<label width>}{<leader width>}
> ```
>
> - ...
> - `<left>` even if bracketed is currently mandatory and it sets the left margin from the left page margin.
> - ...
>
> ```
> \titlecontents{<section>}[<left>]{<above-code>}
>               {<numbered-entry-format>}{<numberless-entry-format>}
>               {<filler-page-format>}[<below-code>]
> ```
>
> Here `<section>`, `<left>` and `<above-code>` like above, ...

To that end, you need to supply the second, optional argument, as it's actually mandatory:

```
% Exercise Environment
\titlecontents{exercise}[0pt]{}{}{}{} % should remove from ToC
```